# Load Spring configuration in Hibernate entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, entity

I want to configure Hibernate to set maximum length for a VARCHAR field. This maximum length is defined in a configuration file, and this configuration file is loaded by a class ValidationConfiguration.

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{

    @Autowired /*I know this is bad practice, 
    I just want to let readers know that this object is instantiated.*/
    private ValidationConfiguration config;

        @Column(length = config.getMaxLength()) /*This gives a "java: element value 
        must be a constant expression"*/
        String description;

        //Get and set
    }
```

Is this possible? If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Possible duplicate [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363969/how-to-set-length-of-an-column-in-hibernate-with-maximum-length)

Comment: It's related, but not a duplicate. I read that question before I posted my own.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it is clearly visible, that You are just defining the `ValidationConfiguration` by `private ValidationConfiguration config;`

But You are not Instantiating the Object.
So, Instantiate the object like `new ValidationConfiguration()` and since you haven't shared the code of `ValidationConfiguration` , i am predicting that your method is `getMaxLength()` not static. If the problem persists, do share the ValidationConfiguration code.
If that is a bean, then you can `autowire` it simply and don't create new instantiation.

Comment: You can assume the object is instantiated. I added an @Autowire now. However, I can't call any method at all inside the annotation. *Should* I be able to call a method of a member variable inside the annotation arguments?

Comment: don't autowire it. Can you check on this statement private ValidationConfiguration config = new ValidationConfiguration();

Comment: I tried adding `ValidationConfiguration config = new ValidationConfiguration();` inside the constructor, but to no avail. Inside of the annotation arguments, the compiler seems to treat `config` as a primitive type. I still get the "java: element value must be a constant expression".